# Polynomial-time logic puzzle using AND/OR/NOT to create <= on N inputs?

Tags: boolean-logic, puzzle, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

So let's say you have n boolean inputs of x1, x2, x3, ..., xn. How do you determine that <= k of your boolean inputs are True using only And/Or/Not logic gates, and doing so in polynomial time?

I'm quite honestly befuddled.

Comment: A good overview of cardinality expressions using counters of various kinds was given by [Carsten Sinz](http://www.carstensinz.de/talks/CP-2005-talk.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. One is to (recursively) make two nets:

- one (A) determining that <= k-1 of boolean inputs x1 ... x[n-1] are True.
- another (B) determining that <= k of boolean inputs x1 ... x[n-1] are True.

Connect them as (B And Not x[n]) Or A

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: What do you want to know? I think that my answer contains the full description of the network.

Comment: Imagine that ´B´ and ´xn´ are both true. In this case, ´k+1´ inputs would be true and the expression should be false. The correct expression should be ´(B And not xn) Or (A And xn)´. However, this solution looks rather exponential than polynomial.

Comment: Fixed, but the expression is polynomial as subexpressions repeat themselves.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ´A And xn´?

Comment: @AxelKemper no, see my message, it is right now.  all x's should be under not, as they make the output "less true".

Comment: @user31264 I see. If A is true, there must bei either k-1 or k true inputs and the overall expression must be true. But I don't get yet, where the common subexpressions are.

Comment: Let Net(i,j) be the net determining that <= k of boolean inputs x1 ... x[j] are True.  Then our target is Net(k,n), it depends on A=Net(k,n-1), B=Net(k-1,n-1).  The net A aka Net(k,n-1) will create Net(k-1,n-2) and Net(k-2,net-2), while the net B will create Net(k-2, n-2) and Net(k-3, n-2). They already have the common subexpression Net(k-2,n-2).  At the following steps more common supexpression will be created.

Comment: @vawd_gandi guess what.